# How do I refactor the jasmine.any() functionality using Chai / Sinon

Tags: javascript, jasmine, bdd, sinon, chai

I have the following code in Jasmine where *add* is a spy.

```
expect(add).toHaveBeenCalledWith('MY_OBJECT_ID', jasmine.any(Object));
```

How would I express this using Chai / Sinon? I know that Sinon would use to.have.been.called.with() but the part I'm having a problem with is the jasmine.any() function.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of digging around and came up with this....

```
expect( add.lastCall.args[0] ).to.equal('MY_OBJECT_ID');
expect( add.lastCall.args[1] ).to.be.an('object');
```

Comment: The second line worked perfectly for my issue.
.to.be.an('object');
replaces the need for jasmine.any(Object)

Answer (score 1):

Sinon has `calledWithMatch()`:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var spy   = sinon.spy();

spy('MY_OBJECT_ID', { foo : 'bar' });

console.log(spy.calledWithMatch('MY_OBJECT_ID',     sinon.match.object) ); // true
console.log(spy.calledWithMatch('NOT_MY_OBJECT_ID', sinon.match.object) ); // false
console.log(spy.calledWithMatch('MY_OBJECT_ID',     sinon.match.number) ); // false
```